# better design for sub-branching if statement sub conditions

Tags: c, coding-style

I am trying to refactor an if statement with multiple sub-conditions. From my current tries, I either have to write the conditions twice, or the intended end function twice. I'd like a cleaner way.

Here is the initial code I had wrote:

```
   if((s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') || (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')){ // cipher uppercase letters
        bool uppercase = true;
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') { // cipher lowercase letters
            bool uppercase = false;
        }
        printf("%c", cipher_letter(s[i], true, k));
    }
    else { // do nothing on non-alphabet letters
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
```

The cleaner way I found right now is this :

```
if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') { // cipher uppercase letters
    printf("%c", cipher_letter(s[i], true, k));
}
else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') { // cipher lowercase letters
    printf("%c", cipher_letter(s[i], false, k));
}
else { // do nothing on non-alphabet letters
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

But then I have to repeat the cipher_letter function.

What would be an even better way to style this?

Comment: What are you trying to do at all? Might be it's not about optimizing your solution but finding a completely *new* solution.

Comment: @Downvoter I'm all for it. The code works, I'm just looking for better style, or as you say a better solution overall. The second version should make clear what I'm doing.

Comment: If someone asks if their solution is right, I don't, as a matter of principle, trust their solution. I can't know if your solution is correct at all. So, I'd appreciate that you state your problem first and then show an implementation. Anyway, your question looks better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I understand the problem you raise, will do that on my next question. (still wanna say my code works I'm only looking for better style, cause I've encountered this if problem many times before)

Comment: Please note that `isalpha()` and `islower()` and `isupper()` are provided with `#include <ctype.h>` for your convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question about the condition, introduce two local variables to cache the result of the two parts of your test.

```
bool isUpper = s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z';
bool isLower = s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z';

if (isUpper || isLower) {
    printf("%c", cipher_letter(s[i], isUpper, k));
}
else { // do nothing on non-alphabet letters
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

The additional names also add clarity about the purpose of the tests, helping comprehension for someone else reading the code later on (this might include you).

**Updated**: I had passed the wrong bool to `cipher_letter`; thanks for the catch.

Comment: great, this is exactly the kind of refactor I was looking for. Will help me a lot every time this problem arises again.

Answer (score 1):

For better design, it might be simplified into:

```
if (isalpha(s[i]))
    putchar(cipher_letter(s[i], isupper(s[i]), k));
else
    putchar(s[i]);
```

or even:

```
putchar(isalpha(s[i]) ? cipher_letter(s[i], isupper(s[i]), k) : s[i]);
```

I would prefer the former, since it looks clearer.

In case of efficiency, both [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) calls are likely to be implemented via macros, that refer to [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) array such as `__ctype_b_loc` (GCC, Clang).